# Swipe List Left to Right + ionic angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am currently new to ionic framework. I have a list view wherein the user should be able to swipe left - right  and right to left.

I can swipe the list item from right to left.

Is there a way to swipe the list element from left to right?

[image]

**CODE**

```
<ion-list >
      <ion-item class="item-icon-right " ng-repeat="alarm in alarmList| filter: alarmName" type="item-text-wrap"  on-swipe-right="swipeRight()" on-swipe-left="acknoledge()" can-swipe="true">

      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

**EDIT:**

I am able to capture the event using **on-swipe-right**,  but the list element animation does not work.

Comment: I've you tried your example on a real device? Animations on desktop happen very quickly but on mobile they use to be seen.

Comment: @Lothre1, I have tried running my app on the device, Yet no solution in sight.

Comment: Try this http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/

Comment: @ShrujanShetty: Are you able to find the solution. i am also looking for the same solution.

Comment: @HituBansal unfortunately ionic did not have the provision to swipe from left to right. So we ended up adding 2 buttons when user swipes from right to left. Hope this helps.

Comment: you could check my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/31816296/3620324

pcagica