# make a list swipe left to right and left to right

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to swipe a list form left to right and right to left
i could make a code that swipes from left to right but i could not do it for right to left

```
 <ion-list >
            <ion-item href="#" ng-repeat="prod in orderInfo.prod">
                <div > Product Name
                    <l style="Padding-left:20%;">{{prod.productName}}</l>                    
                </div>
                <div> Customer Item Code
                    <l style="Padding-left:3%;">{{prod.customerItemCode}}<l>
                </div>
                <div> Item Code  
                    <l style="Padding-left:15%;">{{prod.ocalaItemCode}}</l>
                </div>  
                <ion-option-button ng-click="passPopup();"  class="button-light icon ion-android-checkmark-circle"></ion-option-button>
                <ion-option-button ng-click="conditionalPopup();" class="button-light icon ion-android-radio-button-on"></ion-option-button>
                <ion-option-button ng-click="failPopup();" class="button-assertive ion-android-cancel"></ion-option-button>
            </ion-item>

        </ion-list>
```

i need to swipe that list from left to right and it should have  buttons

different views of my thought:
view 0: Swipe right: thumbnails,
view 1: centre content: "Product name, customer item code,.....",
view 2: swipe left: three buttons"pass, conditional pass, fail ".

In a list on right to left swipe 3 buttons are visible. On swiping left to right the list appears again back as a list, again on swiping the list left to right another set of 3 buttons should appear, Hence totally 6 buttons in a list-item.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i swipe left-right my ionic item list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153543/how-can-i-swipe-left-right-my-ionic-item-list)

Comment: could u help me to bind this code i am a beginner

Comment: Do check my updated question