# Is there an option to swipe right for <ion-option-button> in ionic 1 framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic v1, and working on swipe left and right on < ion-list> items.
 I would like to know that is there **any options to swipe right for < ion-option-button>** in ionic 1 framework? Since the < ion-option-button> creates a button, that is visible when the item is **swiped only to the left** by the user.

When I ran a search, it said that swipe right was not yet implemented for ionic1.

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153543/how-to-swipe-from-left-to-right-ionic-list-item

Comment: Thanks @sunielkalwani, it helped me in resolving.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved:**
The tag *< item-swipe-pane direction ="right">* allows us to swipe right, also we would need to modify css accordingly.

```
  <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <item-swipe-pane direction="right">
                <button class="button button-assertive swipe-btn">
                           Delete
                 </button>
            </item-swipe-pane>
            <item-swipe-pane direction="left">
                <button class="button button-positive swipe-btn">
                              Duplicate
              </button>
            </item-swipe-pane>
        </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

[Swipe Right Direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx9C6.png)

[Swipe Left Direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohT5P.png)